# How can i learn which ip's do i have on linux vps server?

Tags: linux, ip

I bought a VPS server yesterday. Server companies support is not avaible for now. I am going to set dns adress. So i know 1 ip number they gave to me, how can i learn how many ip's i have and what are they? Is there command for ubuntu for that? Or any other way?

Answer (score 3):

`ip addr` as root is the way to go.

Comment: inet xx.xxx.39.203/24 brd xx.xxx.39.255 scope global eth0

i am getting this result, so it means what ?

Answer (score 2):

`/sbin/ifconfig -a`

Will result in something like

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1C:C0:78:D2:74  
          inet addr:aaa.bbb.ccc.dddd  Bcast:xxx.yyy.zzz.nnn  Mask:255.255.240.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:423575721 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:126628915 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3433267581 (3.1 GiB)  TX bytes:4221095056 (3.9 GiB)
          Interrupt:17 Base address:0x6000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:9838921 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9838921 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4205604044 (3.9 GiB)  TX bytes:4205604044 (3.9 GiB)
```

Any IP address *not* assigned to `lo` is a public IP address (confirm that by trying to ping it from another machine)

Answer (score 1):

/sbin/ip addr as non-root ;-)

```
[kaman@host-10 ~]$ /sbin/ip a|grep -oP "inet (\d+\.){3}\d+"
inet 127.0.0.1
inet 192.168.0.10
inet 192.168.54.2
```

Comment: This may or may not work, depending on the actual permissions of `/sbin` and `/sbin/ip`. I wouldn't count on it.